# Merge android.graphics.Path instances?

Tags: android

Is it possible to merge several paths?

In the following example, I add 3 paths to the resulting 'p4'.
Drawing with Paint.Style.STROKE works. 
So it seems to be a problem with the Path.FillType ?

```
    public void drawTest3(Canvas canvas){

        Path p1,p2,p3,p4;
        p1 = new Path();
        p2 = new Path();
        p3 = new Path();
        p4 = new Path();

        // create 3 coordinates that form a triangle
        float[] start = new float[]{(float)getWidth()/2,(float)getHeight()/2};
        float[] point1 = new float[]{0.0f,(float)getHeight()};
        float[] point2 = new float[]{(float)getWidth(),(float)getHeight()};

        p1.moveTo(start[0], start[1]);
        p1.lineTo(point1[0], point1[1]);

        p2.moveTo(point1[0], point1[1]);
        p2.lineTo(point2[0], point2[1]);

        p3.moveTo(point2[0], point2[1]);
        p3.lineTo(start[0], start[1]);

        // add all 3 paths to p4 
        p4.addPath(p1);
        p4.addPath(p2);
        p4.addPath(p3);

        // draw
        canvas.drawARGB(0xff, 0xdd, 0xdd, 0xdd);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(0x33333333);
        canvas.drawPath(p4, paint);

    }
```

Regards, Roland

Answer (score 1):

This is how I joined two paths from two different methods. Each one return a Path that.

```
Path p = new Path();
p = beggining();
p.addPath(continue(p)); 
p.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only use fill if the path is closed, so you'd want to call p4.close() before you draw it.

Comment: Added p4.close() but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

i think you might have to close each path? path classes can sometimes yield unexpected results like this.